# About java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote some code for my assignment, 'heap sort'.

1. I received input file name.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("insert 'input file name' : ");
   String fileName = in.nextLine();
   in.close();
   ```
2. Then I read that file.

   ```
   in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
   ArrayList<Integer> source = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   MyIntHeap heap = new MyIntHeap();
   for(int idx=0; in.hasNextInt(); ++idx){
       source.add(in.nextInt());
       heap.add(source.get(idx));
   }
   in.close();
   ```
3. Finally, I tried to receive output file name...

   ```
   in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("insert 'output file name' : ");
   fileName = in.nextLine();
   in.close();
   ```

At this point, program threw an error to me.

```
insert 'input file name' : abc.txt
insert 'output file name' : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:13)
```

For now I solve problem as

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("insert 'input file name' : ");
    String inputFile = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("insert 'output file name' : ");
    String outputFile = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
```

But I'd like to know why the problem happened.

Comment: Use code instead of pictures for your console.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit the question to put the text of your error in the question. Also "This is my first question, nice to meet you" is not relevant and should be edited out. Stick to the technical content.

Comment: Nice to meet you too. :-) Following the link you can solve your doubts about Scanner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: @CacheStaheli I edited. Thank you.

Comment: @paisanco Oh, I didn't consider about that. I edited. Thank you.

Comment: @RubioRic Thank you for comment. I read the document following your link, but I think there's no connection with my question.

Comment: You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
...
in.close();
```

The problem here is that you are closing a `Scanner` which is reading `System.in`. This also closes `System.in`.

The solution is that you should just not close the `Scanner`.

You should always close resources that *you've* created. `System.in` isn't a resource you've created, so you don't need to close it.

Comment: Thank you.

I thought that I should close when I use Scanner, because eclipse says "Resource leak: 'in' is never closed" when I didn't write that.

Then, 2. in = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); ─ in this case, is it right to close Scanner?

Comment: Yes, you should close the Scanner that's reading from a file. IDE warnings aren't perfect so very occasionally you can ignore them. `new Scanner(System.in)` is just one of those rare cases where you should ignore the warning.